# How to achieve Wordwrap of List Elements inside a Flexbox Layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox, word-wrap

Here is how the elements according to my question look like at the moment:
[Flexbox Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbCs3.png)

What I want to achieve is, that the text inside the unordered-list elements is wrapped to the next line if it's too long. What happens now is, that the whole list jumps into a new line (see the 2nd example in the linked image).

I want the list to stay right next to the image on the same row (until some media query is reached to break with `flex-direction: column`).

Any possible solutions?

```css
.team-row {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* Safari */
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  margin-top: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  padding: 5px;
}

.team-header {
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #F6B80B;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="team-row">
  <strong class="team-header">Wolfgang Niepel</strong>
  <img class="team-image" src="http://wp.fahrschuleniepel.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/image.png" alt="Wolfgang Niepel" width="100" height="133">
  <ul class="team-description">
    <li>Fahrlehrer seit: 1964</li>
    <li>selbstständig seit: 1968</li>
    <li>sonstiges: Gründung der Fahrschule Niepel am 01.12.1968.</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="team-row">
  <strong class="team-header">Jens Niepel</strong>
  <img class="team-image" src="http://wp.fahrschuleniepel.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/jens_niepel_100.jpg" alt="Jens Niepel" width="100" height="133">
  <ul class="team-description">
    <li>Fahrlehrer seit: 1983</li>
    <li>bei Fahrschule Niepel seit: 1983</li>
    <li>sonstiges: Seit 2001 leite ich unser Büro und bin Ihr Ansprechpartner zu allen Fragen rund um Ihre Ausbildung.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have to use `flex-flow: row wrap;`? Why not just wrap the "columns" part with a `div` with `display: flex` and that's it?

Answer (score 1):

Add `flex: 1;` to `.team-description`.

This will set:

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: 0%;
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Can you explain why? It just lets the ul and the inner Elements grow regardless of the Image right?

Comment: Have a look at [this tool](http://algid.com/Flex-Designer), a good starting point to play around, design and understand `flexbox`.